# how to separate optionals from arguments in bash?

Tags: bash, shell

My script needs two arguments to run.

It can have optionals if needed so I want to ensure these properties so I have written the following script

```
 if [ $# -lt 3 ]
    then
     echo "This command need 3 arguments"
    else
     echo $1 $2 $3
  fi
```

observed that "$#" counts total number of arguments passed including the optionals

```
OUTPUT :
sh my_script.sh -o optional1 -r.
```

It works but not as intended as my check fails.

```
Expected Output :(two arguments are compulsory)
sh my_script.sh arg1 arg2 --> should work
sh my_script.sh -o optional1 -r optional2 --> throw error that it requires two arguments
sh my_script.sh -o optional1 -r optional2 arg1 arg2 --> should work
```

Comment: Use `getopts` to handle this.

Comment: @Sato Katsura that handles optionals I understand ... but my problem is I am unable to check that the user must input two arguments for sure

Comment: @PrabhuKonchada Please explain the problem more clearly , what does the -r flag do ?

Comment: @User112638726 let -r do some x operation which I am not worried about.. what really worries me is I cannot keep a check on the number of arguments which should be definitely given to do the primary function of my script if optionals are present. I may not have explained this clearly so ask questions if any which I would be happy to reply back. Thanks for your time and efforts :)

Comment: @User112638726 I have used -o and -r to show that there are two optionals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without getopts, but pretty much the same thing, i prefer this way because it is easier to add long args.

```
#!/bin/bash


while true;do

        case $1 in

        '-o'|'--optional')
                optional1=$2
                shift 2
                ;;
        '-r')
                optional2=$2
                shift 2
                ;;
        *)
                break
                ;;
        esac
done

if [[ $# -lt 2 ]];then
    echo Too few args.
    exit 1
fi

echo $optional1
echo $optional2
```

Obviously it could be more robust as this will take multiple of the same flags.

Comment: check this case myscript.sh -r "" -o "" arg1 arg2  ?

Comment: @PrabhuKonchada I didn't think -r took arguments as it doesn't in your question ?

Comment: @PrabhuKonchada There you go

Comment: Is there a better approach than checking with flags to avoid repetition of optionals ??? [Eg :my script.sh -o "" -o "" ]

Answer (score 3):

**Note**, `$#` reports the **number of arguments** (`positional parameters`). It doesn't care what they are. Anything on the command line is considered an argument. (e.g. `somevar` or `-o`). So to distinguish between `-foo` and `foo`, you will need to either write an interpreter, or use `getopts` as provided by others (as that interpreter)

While `getopts` is fine, I generally want my own interpreter. To provide a custom interpreter in `sh`, you will generally use a `while loop`, `shift` and a `case` statement to check each positional parameter and respond accordingly. While string manipulation is somewhat limited in `sh` compared to `bash` it is sufficient.

An example that fits your requirements could be:

```
#!/bin/sh

if [ $# -lt 2 ]; then
    printf "This command need 2 arguments\n"
    exit 1
fi

let nargs=0

while [ "$1" != "" ]; do
    printf " processing: %s\n" "$1"
    case "$1" in
        -r  )   shift
                [ "$1" = "" -o  `expr index "$1" "-"` -eq 1 ] && \
                { printf "error: -r requires an option.\n"; exit 1; }
                r_var="$1"
                printf "   -r %s\n" "$r_var"
                let nargs=$nargs+1
                ;;
        -*  )   ;;  ## don't count '-x' arguments as options (change as needed)
        *   )   let nargs=$nargs+1
                ;;
    esac
    shift
done

if [ $nargs -lt 2 ]; then
    printf "\n Two compulsory arguments not given.\n\n"
    exit 1
else
    printf "\n required arguments satisfied.\n\n"
fi


exit 0
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ sh params.sh arg1 arg2
 processing: arg1
 processing: arg2

 required arguments satisfied.


$ sh params.sh -o optional -r
 processing: -o
 processing: optional
 processing: -r
error: -r requires an option.


$ sh params.sh -o optional -r arg1 arg2
 processing: -o
 processing: optional
 processing: -r
   -r arg1
 processing: arg2

 required arguments satisfied.


$ sh params.sh -o arg2
 processing: -o
 processing: arg2

 Two compulsory arguments not given.
```

---

**Checking for Duplicate Arguments**

A nested `for` loop checking the positional parameters for duplicates is probably the best way to check for duplicate arguments if you don't want to try and cover everything in the `case` statement. One approach would be to check at the beginning of your script:

```
#!/bin/sh

let args=2

## check duplicate arguments
for i ; do
    for j in $(seq $args $#); do
        printf "i: %s  j: %s compare %s %s\n" $i $j $i ${!j}  ## delete - just for info
        if [ $i = ${!j} ]; then
            printf "error: duplicate args [ %s = %s ], exiting.\n" $i ${!j}
            exit 1;
        fi
    done
    let args=$args+1
done

exit 0
```

**Examples/Output**

```
$ sh pdupes.sh a b c d e
i: a  j: 2 compare a b
i: a  j: 3 compare a c
i: a  j: 4 compare a d
i: a  j: 5 compare a e
i: b  j: 3 compare b c
i: b  j: 4 compare b d
i: b  j: 5 compare b e
i: c  j: 4 compare c d
i: c  j: 5 compare c e
i: d  j: 5 compare d e

$ sh pdupes.sh a b c d b e
i: a  j: 2 compare a b
i: a  j: 3 compare a c
i: a  j: 4 compare a d
i: a  j: 5 compare a b
i: a  j: 6 compare a e
i: b  j: 3 compare b c
i: b  j: 4 compare b d
i: b  j: 5 compare b b
error: duplicate args [ b = b ], exiting.
```

---

**Preventing Accepting Argument Twice**

In addition to the loop check above which will catch any duplicate, you can also add an option to the `case` statement that will prevent accepting an argument twice. It is up to you whether you just want to skip the duplicate or flag it and exit. In the case of your `-o` with optional argument, I would try something like the following which accepts an optional argument, tests it is not another `-x` type and checks whether it was already set. If it passes all the tests, `o_var is set and by being set, it can't be set again:

```
    -o  )   shift
            [ "$1" = "" -o  `expr index "$1" "-"` -eq 1 -o ! -z $o_var ] && \
            { printf "duplicate value for '-o' received, exiting\n"; exit 1; } || \
            o_var="$1" && let nargs=$nargs+1
            printf "   -o %s\n" "$o_var"
            ;;
```

**Slight Variations Controlling Response to Duplicate**

There are two additional ways of handling multiple attempts to set `-o`. The first is to just exit on any second appearance of `-o` in the argument list (regardless of whether there is an attempt to set the optional variable associated with `-o`):

```
    -o  )   shift
            ## throw error on any second instance of '-o' 
            if [ -z "$o_var" ]; then
                if [ ! `expr index "$1" "-"` -eq 1 -a "$1" != "" ]; then
                    o_var="$1"
                    let nargs=$nargs+1
                    printf "   -o %s\n" "$o_var"
                fi
            else
                    printf "error: multiple attempts to set '-o', exiting.\n" "$o_var" "$1"
                    exit 1                
            fi
            ;;
```

**Examples**

Both attempts to set `-o` a second time are treated the same:

```
$ sh params.sh -o foo -r arg1 arg2 -o bar
$ sh params.sh -o foo -r arg1 arg2 -o
 processing: -o
   -o foo
 processing: -r
   -r arg1
 processing: arg2
 processing: -o
error: multiple attempts to set '-o', exiting.
```

The other possibility is to only throw an error only if there is a second attempt to set the optional variable associated with `-o`. (e.g. if the second `-o` is harmless, ignore it):

```
    -o  )   shift
            ## throw error only if second instance of '-o' has optional argument
            if [ "$1" != "" -a ! `expr index "$1" "-"` -eq 1 ]; then
                if [ -z "$o_var" ]; then
                    o_var="$1"
                    let nargs=$nargs+1
                    printf "   -o %s\n" "$o_var"
                else
                    printf "error: multiple attempts to set '-o'. (%s, now '%s')\n" "$o_var" "$1"
                    exit 1
                fi
            fi
            ;;
```

**Examples**

```
$ sh params.sh -o foo -r arg1 arg2 -o bar
 processing: -o
   -o foo
 processing: -r
   -r arg1
 processing: arg2
 processing: -o
error: multiple attempts to set '-o'. (foo, now 'bar')

$ sh params.sh -o foo -r arg1 arg2 -o
 processing: -o
   -o foo
 processing: -r
   -r arg1
 processing: arg2
 processing: -o

 required arguments satisfied.
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and effort in answering my question :)

Comment: How should we avoid repetition of optionals ??

Comment: A little confused can you help me with an example ?

Comment: Sorry I forgot we were POSIX only here. You can use a `for i ; do` loop to walk through each argument and compare `$i = $1 -> $#` for duplicates or include a `case` statement for each option taking an optional argument and set a flag if it is filled.

Comment: I added an example to the end of my answer.

Comment: some bug maybe it doesn't work for happy cases : my script.sh -O "optional1" arg1 arg2 --> exits with "error: duplicate args [ arg2 = arg2 ], exiting"

Comment: I don't want this to happen actually my script -O "optional1" -O "optional1" arg1 arg2 --> should fail with -O repeated twice

Comment: I added a test case for `-o` at the end of the answer that will prevent the `-o ... -o ...` scenario. That is the beauty of writing your own interpreter. It will behave exactly like **you** want it to.

Answer (score 2):

1. Process the options with `getopts`.

   ```
   r_flag=0
   o_flag="default value"
   while getopts o:r arg
   do
       case "$arg" in
       (o) o_flag="$OPTARG";;
       (r) r_flag=1;;
       (*) echo "Unrecognized option $arg" >&2; exit 1;;
       esac
   done
   ```
2. After the loop doing that, use `shift $(($OPTIND - 1))` to get rid of the processed options.
3. Now you can check that there are at least 2 more arguments:

   ```
   if [ $# -lt 2 ]
   then
       echo "Usage: $(basename $0 .sh) [-o option][-r] arg1 arg2 ..." >&2
       exit 1
   fi
   ```

Comment: Should it not be less than 2 ?

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler this case doesn't work sh test2.sh -r "op1" -o "op2" arg1 --> script executes

Comment: I wasn't clear whether the `-r` option took an argument.  If it does, change the `getopts` line to include a colon after the `r`, and fix the clause in the `case` to capture `$OPTARG` like for `-o`, and set a default, etc.  it is routine, easy systematic changes.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler How to avoid repetition of optionals ??

Comment: Set initial values of flags to empty (`o_flag=""`, etc).  When an option is detected, check if the flag is empty; if not, complain.  After the loop, if the flag is still empty, set it to a default value.